# Getting and setting Gstreamer element properties using C++

Tags: c++, gstreamer, glib, gobject

I'm writing a minimal C++ wrapper around the Gstreamer library. I have a class `Element`, which represents an Gstreamer element.

```
class Element
{
private:
    property* properties; 
public:
    gchar* name;
    GstElement* type; //represents the actual element
    Element();
    Element(gchar* name, gchar* type);
    Element(gchar * type);
    ~Element();
    void set_property(gchar* name, gchar* value);
    void set_property(gchar* name, gint value);
    void set_property(gchar* name, gfloat value);
    void get_property(gchar* name);
    int link_with(Element& e);   
};
```

`set_property` is straight forward:

```
    void Element::set_property(gchar* name, gchar* value) {
        g_object_set(this->type, name, value, NULL);
        // include further validations
    }
```

1. I'm overloading the methods `set_property` because of the different value types that can occour. Is this the way to go? Or is there a way to unify the value parameter?
2. How do I get a property without knowing its value type?
   The [documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/gstreamer-sdk/data/docs/2012.5/gobject/gobject-The-Base-Object-Type.html#g-object-get) suggest this example:

   ```
    gint intval;
    gchar *strval;
    GObject *objval;
    //my_object would be the Gstreamer element
     g_object_get (my_object,
                   "int-property", &intval,
                   "str-property", &strval,
                   "property-name", &objval,
                   NULL);

     // Do something with intval, strval, objval

     g_free (strval);
     g_object_unref (objval);
   ```

How do I check which variable `intval, strval, objval` was set?

PS:
I can't use the official Gstreamer C++ wrapper, since it's not in active development and there is no real documentation about the usage.

Comment: Your code isn't "C/C++" (no code is, since there's no such language). It's not even C. It's plain and simple C++ and only C++. Don't use the term "C/C++" and don't tag languages you're not actually writing your program in.

Comment: Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: You may refer to gst-inspect source code : https://github.com/GStreamer/gstreamer/blob/master/tools/gst-inspect.c